# Python & Excel: Append a list as column (specific column and row) into existing excel

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe

I have encountered a problem in python.

I would want to append a column(list) into an existing excel.

I changed my excel into a dataframe but i do not know how to append the list into it.

Original:

[image]

I want to append the list. However, my rows start from 8 instead of 1.

I have tried the code below but encountered error.

```
 df1 = read_excel(file_name, sheet_name=my_sheet, engine='openpyxl')
 h = [2,3,4,5]
 df1['List'] = h
ValueError: Length of values (4) does not match length of index (14)
```

Expected result:

[image]

Appreciate any help. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your excel includes empty rows and your python is reading them.
To make sure - print out your df:

```
display(df1)
```

If this is the case try filtering them out:

```
df1 = read_excel(file_name, sheet_name=my_sheet, engine='openpyxl', na_filter=True)
```

Alternatively, you can drop the empty rows after you read the excel:

```
df1 = read_excel(file_name, sheet_name=my_sheet, engine='openpyxl')
df1 = df1.dropna()
```